# USB C headset (Huawei) only recognised on Windows 11 once after PC restart, after subsequent unplugging and plugging in not recognised anymore

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-11, headphones, usb-c

I encountered a most peculiar problem. I have a Huawei USB C headset (don't know the model, bought it second hand). It works fine with my Fairphone 4, sound, mic, volume keys, everything. On my Windows 11 PC (HP Zbook G5) it is recognised after I restart my PC, and then it plays music fine. If I then remove the headset from the PC and reinsert it into the PC, it is not recognised anymore and I can't play music anymore. On device manager it then doesn't show up either. Only when I then restart the PC, and reinsert the headset, it is recognised again.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

I tested on a iPad and there the headset work fine, also after unplugging and replugging.

I also had a look at device properties (in device manager) for the headset. In the events tab the following is mentioned (under "information"):

```
Device settings for SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.0.00000000}.{1cf6f0cf-f035-43ff-8cc0-fa0c8de2b1a2} were not migrated from previous OS installation due to partial or ambiguous device match.

Last Device Instance Id: SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.0.00000000}.{0e58beb4-9909-45a6-8a49-780c19045ff5}

Class Guid: {c166523c-fe0c-4a94-a586-f1a80cfbbf3e}

Location Path:

Migration Rank: 0xF00000000000F120

Present: false

Status: 0xC0000719

---

Device SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.0.00000000}.{1cf6f0cf-f035-43ff-8cc0-fa0c8de2b1a2} was configured.
Driver Name: audioendpoint.inf
Class Guid: {c166523c-fe0c-4a94-a586-f1a80cfbbf3e}
Driver Date: 05/06/2022
Driver Version: 10.0.22621.1
Driver Provider: Microsoft
Driver Section: NO_DRV
Driver Rank: 0xFF0000
Matching Device Id: MMDEVAPI\AudioEndpoints
Outranked Drivers: c_swdevice.inf:SWD\GenericRaw:00FF3001
Device Updated: false
Parent Device: USB\VID_12D1&PID_3A07&MI_00\6&1c44d17e&0&0000

---
Device SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.0.00000000}.{1cf6f0cf-f035-43ff-8cc0-fa0c8de2b1a2} was started.

Driver Name: audioendpoint.inf

Class Guid: {c166523c-fe0c-4a94-a586-f1a80cfbbf3e}

Service:

Lower Filters:

Upper Filters:
```

[image]

Comment: Do you simply unplug it, or safely eject USB device? You might try a third-party tool, such as HotSwap, http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm , to "safely eject" the headset, to alert Windows to the fact that it has been unplugged and can then be inserted again. Please let me know if that helps -- if so, I'll make it an answer, and if not, delete this.

Comment: I simply unplug it, there is no option to "safely eject" because it doesn't show up under the icon where a USB device would usually show up (bottom right in windows). I've installed hotswap, as per your recommendation. However the last few times that I've tried the headphones don't get recognised at all (even after a PC restart), so I'm not able to "safely eject" them and therefore can't test your solution. Also, the headphones  don't show up under the hotswap icon either (I've "checked" all device types in the menu).